# Python: How to get string between matches?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have

```
FILE = open("file.txt", "r") #long text file
TEXT = FILE.read()

#long identification code with dots (.) and slashes (-)
regex = "process \d\d\d\d\d\d\d\-\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\.\d+\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d"
SRC = re.findall(regex, TEXT, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
```

How can I get the text between first char of first occurence `SRC[i]` and first char of next ocurrence `SRC[i+1]` and so on? Couldn't find any straight forward satisfatory answer...

MORE INFO EDIT:

```
pattern = 'process \d{7}\-\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\d+\.\d{2}\.\d{4}'

sample_input = "Process 1234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 -  text title and long text description with no assured pattern Process 2234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 : chars and more text Process 3234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 - more text process 3234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 (...)"

sample_output[0] = "Process 1234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 -  text title and long text description with no assured pattern "
sample_output[1] = "Process 2234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 : chars and more text "
sample_output[2] = "Process 3234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 - more text "
sample_output[3] = "process 3234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234    "
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input and expected output.

Comment: You can shorten your regex to: `\d{7}\-\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\d+\.\d{2}\.\d{4}`

Comment: what exactly are you asking? Show some of your input,I imagine split may be useful

Comment: added sample in and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(Process \d{7}\-\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\d+\.\d{2}\.\d{4}.*?)(?=Process)|(Process \d{7}\-\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\d+\.\d{2}\.\d{4}.*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/vT8qH9/1)**

[image])

**Match information**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-105] `Process 1234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 -  text title and long text description with no assured pattern `
MATCH 2
1.  [105-168]   `Process 2234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 : chars and more text `
MATCH 3
1.  [168-221]   `Process 3234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 - more text `
MATCH 4
2.  [221-267]   `Process 3234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 (...)`
```

You can use this code:

```
sample_input = "Process 1234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 -  text title and long text description with no assured pattern Process 2234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 : chars and more text Process 3234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 - more text process 3234567-89.1234.12431242.12.1234 (...)"
m = re.match(r"(Process \d{7}\-\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\d+\.\d{2}\.\d{4}.*?)(?=Process)|(Process \d{7}\-\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\d+\.\d{2}\.\d{4}.*)", sample_input)
m.group(1)       # The first parenthesized subgroup.
m.groups()       # Return a tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1 up to however many groups are in the pattern
```

Comment: the regex looks nice, but I don't know what `re` python function to use and how to parse the found matchs

Comment: @Sarchophagi this is a simple regex you only need to grab the content from capturing group. If you enter in the link I provided in my answer you can go to the Code Generator section so see how to use it

Comment: nice. got it working with the example, but not with the true big file. Its grabs NO match. Maybe its too big? (~4Mb .txt) Or maybe its because it has special chars like á ã à ó é?

Comment: @Sarchophagi that would be a different question than the current one. I think you should create a new question asking about this and you may consider closing this one since I've already answered to it

Comment: in fact `m.groups()` is returning a tuple  with `("first ocorrence", none)` only. odd..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59390/discussion-between-sarchophagi-and-fede).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a string `some_str = 'abcARelevant_SubstringAcba'` and you want the string between the first `A` and the second `A`; i.e. the desired output is `'Relevant_Substring'`.

You can find the indices of occurrences of `A` in `some_str` with the following line: 
`inds = [a.start() for a in re.finditer('A', some_str)]`

So now `inds = [3, 22]`. Now `some_str[inds[0]+1:inds[1]` will contain `'Relevant_Substring'`.

This should be extensible to your issue.

**EDIT:** Here's a concrete example.

Suppose you have a file "file.txt" that contains the following text:

```
Stuff I don't want.
0
Stuff I do want.
1
More stuff I don't want.
```

You want to use all digits (0-9) as separators. Therefore, both `0` and `1` above will act as separators. Try the following code:

```
import re
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()
patt = re.compile('[0-9]')
inds = [a.start() for a in re.finditer(patt, data)]
print data[inds[0]+1:inds[1]]
```

This should print out `Stuff I do want.`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need re to find a string between two chars:

```
some_str = 'abcARelevant_SubstringAcba'
print some_str.split("A",2)[1]
Relevant_Substring
```