# Python re.match() not working on string with accentuated chars

Tags: python, regex, character-encoding

PAttern is working ok with test subject containing no accentuated char like á é í ã õ ñ 
But simply returns no matches when I try it over the actual Portuguese-BR accentuated text.

Tried change encodings but got nothing.. Any help?

EDIT: [Regex complete info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25319263/1190288)

> HEX sample imput: 50:72:6f:63:65:73:73:6f:20:31:30:35:36:39:32:32:2d:38:34:2e:32:30:31:33:2e:38:2e
>   :32:36:2e:30:31:30:30:20:2d:20:45:78:65:63:75:c3:a7:c3:a3:6f:20:64:65:20:54:c3:a
>   d:74:75:6c:6f:20:45:78:74:72:61:6a:75:64:69:63:69:61:6c:20:2d:20:45:73:70:c3:a9:
>   63:69:65:73:20:64:65:20:43:6f:6e:74:72:61:74:6f:73:20:2d:20:4d:4f:42:49:4c:49:4e
>   :53:20:46:4f:52:4d:41:c3:87:c3:83:4f:20:50:52:4f:46:49:53:53:49:4f:4e:41:4c:20:4
>   5:4d:20:42:45:4c:45:5a:41:20:4c:54:44:41:2e:20:2d:20:4a:55:4c:49:41:4e:41:20:4d:
>   41:52:41:4e:48:c3:83:4f:20:50:4f:52:54:4f:20:44:41:20:53:49:4c:56:45:49:52:41:20
>   :2d:20:56:69:73:74:6f:73:2e:20:44:65:66:69:72:6f:20:6f:20:70:65:64:69:64:6f:20:7
>   0:61:72:61:20:61:20:70:65:73:71:75:69:73:61:20:64:65:20:62:65:6e:73:20:64:61:20:
>   70:61:72:74:65:20:72:65:71:75:65:72:69:64:61:20:4a:55:4c:49:41:4e:41:20:4d:41:52
>   :41:4e:48:c3:83:4f:20:50:4f:52:54:4f:20:44:41:20:53:49:4c:56:45:49:52:41:2c:20:4
>   3:50:46:20:30:33:30:2e:37:39:37:2e:35:36:34:2d:39:35:20:28:64:65:63:6c:61:72:61:
>   c3:a7:c3:a3:6f:20:64:6f:73:20:63:69:6e:63:6f:20:c3:ba:6c:74:69:6d:6f:73:20:65:78
>   :65:72:63:c3:ad:63:69:6f:73:29:2c:20:6f:20:71:75:61:6c:20:c3:a9:20:72:65:61:6c:6
>   9:7a:61:64:6f:2c:20:6e:65:73:74:61:20:64:61:74:61:2c:20:70:6f:72:20:6d:65:69:6f:
>   20:64:65:20:6f:66:c3:ad:63:69:6f:20:65:6e:76:69:61:64:6f:20:c3:a0:20:52:65:63:65
>   :69:74:61:20:46:65:64:65:72:61:6c:2c:20:70:72:6f:74:6f:63:6f:6c:61:64:6f:20:65:6
>   c:65:74:72:6f:6e:69:63:61:6d:65:6e:74:65:2c:20:70:6f:72:20:69:6e:74:65:72:6d:c3:
>   a9:64:69:6f:20:64:6f:20:73:69:73:74:65:6d:61:20:49:4e:46:4f:4a:55:44:2e:20:49:6e
>   :74:69:6d:65:2d:73:65:2e:20:2d:20:41:44:56:3a:20:4d:41:54:48:45:55:53:20:44:45:2
>   0:4f:4c:49:56:45:49:52:41:20:54:41:56:41:52:45:53:20:28:4f:41:42:20:31:36:30:37:
>   31:31:2f:53:50:29:50:72:6f:63:65:73:73:6f:20:31:30:35:36:39:32:32:2d:38:34:2e:32
>   :30:31:33:2e:38:2e:32:36:2e:30:31:30:30:20:2d:20:45:78:65:63:75:c3:a7:c3:a3:6f:2
>   0:64:65:20:54:c3:ad:74:75:6c:6f:20:45:78:74:72:61:6a:75:64:69:63:69:61:6c:20:2d:
>   20:45:73:70:c3:a9:63:69:65:73:20:64:65:20:43:6f:6e:74:72:61:74:6f:73:20:2d:20:4d
>   :4f:42:49:4c:49:4e:53:20:46:4f:52:4d:41:c3:87:c3:83:4f:20:50:52:4f:46:49:53:53:4
>   9:4f:4e:41:4c:20:45:4d:20:42:45:4c:45:5a:41:20:4c:54:44:41:2e:20:2d:20:4a:55:4c:
>   49:41:4e:41:20:4d:41:52:41:4e:48:c3:83:4f:20:50:4f:52:54:4f:20:44:41:20:53:49:4c
>   :56:45:49:52:41:20:2d:20:56:69:73:74:6f:73:2e:20:31:29:20:43:69:c3:aa:6e:63:69:6
>   1:20:64:61:20:72:65:73:70:6f:73:74:61:20:64:6f:20:6f:66:c3:ad:63:69:6f:20:65:78:
>   70:65:64:69:64:6f:20:c3:a0:20:52:65:63:65:69:74:61:20:46:65:64:65:72:61:6c:2c:20
>   :66:69:63:61:6e:64:6f:20:6f:73:20:64:61:64:6f:73:20:73:69:67:69:6c:6f:73:6f:73:2
>   0:61:72:71:75:69:76:61:64:6f:73:20:65:6d:20:70:61:73:74:61:20:70:72:c3:b3:70:72:
>   69:61:2e:20:32:29:20:50:6f:72:20:63:6f:6e:73:65:67:75:69:6e:74:65:2c:20:61:20:70
>   :61:72:74:65:20:65:78:65:71:75:65:6e:74:65:20:64:65:76:65:20:6d:61:6e:69:66:65:7
>   3:74:61:72:2d:73:65:2c:20:65:6d:20:63:69:6e:63:6f:20:64:69:61:73:2e:20:4e:6f:20:
>   73:69:6c:c3:aa:6e:63:69:6f:2c:20:61:6f:20:61:72:71:75:69:76:6f:2e:20:49:6e:74:69
>   :6d:65:2d:73:65:2e:20:2d:20:41:44:56:3a:20:4d:41:54:48:45:55:53:20:44:45:20:4f:4
>   c:49:56:45:49:52:41:20:54:41:56:41:52:45:53:20:28:4f:41:42:20:31:36:30:37:31:31:
>   2f:53:50:29:50:72:6f:63:65:73:73:6f:20:31:30:35:37:32:38:30:2d:31:35:2e:32:30:31
>   :34:2e:38:2e:32:36:2e:30:31:30:30

Comment: Please post the code that isn't working.

Comment: Also post the Python version, contents/type of the `str`, `bytes` or `unicode`, and yes the example patterns and code for the `re.match()` line.

Comment: Also actual data that works and data that doesn't work, both dumped as hex.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with accented characters. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25319263/3903832) provided to you doesn't work because:

1. In the new input the word *Process* was replaced with *Processo*.
2. The new input has several instances of the regular expression pattern, so `re.findall` should be invoked, rather than `re.match` (in fact, since the old input has several instances as well, that solution won't work perfectly there either).

Therefore, here is the correct solution:

```
>>> print input
Processo 1056922-84.2013.8.26.0100 - Execução de Título Extrajudicial - Espécies de Contratos - MOBILINS FORMAÇÃO PROFISSIONAL EM BELEZA LTDA. - JULIANA MARANHÃO PORTO DA SILVEIRA - Vistos. Defiro o pedido para a pesquisa de bens da parte requerida JULIANA MARANHÃO PORTO DA SILVEIRA, CPF 030.797.564-95 (declaração dos cinco últimos exercícios), o qual é realizado, nesta data, por meio de ofício enviado à Receita Federal, protocolado eletronicamente, por intermédio do sistema INFOJUD. Intime-se. - ADV: MATHEUS DE OLIVEIRA TAVARES (OAB 160711/SP)Processo 1056922-84.2013.8.26.0100 - Execução de Título Extrajudicial - Espécies de Contratos - MOBILINS FORMAÇÃO PROFISSIONAL EM BELEZA LTDA. - JULIANA MARANHÃO PORTO DA SILVEIRA - Vistos. 1) Ciência da resposta do ofício expedido à Receita Federal, ficando os dados sigilosos arquivados em pasta própria. 2) Por conseguinte, a parte exequente deve manifestar-se, em cinco dias. No silêncio, ao arquivo. Intime-se. - ADV: MATHEUS DE OLIVEIRA TAVARES (OAB 160711/SP)Processo 1057280-15.2014.8.26.0100
>>> regex = re.compile('(Processo \\d{7}\\-\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}\\.\\d+\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}.*?)(?=Processo)|(Processo \\d{7}\\-\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}\\.\\d+\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}.*)')
>>> regex.findall(y)
[('Processo 1056922-84.2013.8.26.0100 - Execu\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o de T\xc3\xadtulo Extrajudicial - Esp\xc3\xa9cies de Contratos - MOBILINS FORMA\xc3\x87\xc3\x83O PROFISSIONAL EM BELEZA LTDA. - JULIANA MARANH\xc3\x83O PORTO DA SILVEIRA - Vistos. Defiro o pedido para a pesquisa de bens da parte requerida JULIANA MARANH\xc3\x83O PORTO DA SILVEIRA, CPF 030.797.564-95 (declara\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o dos cinco \xc3\xbaltimos exerc\xc3\xadcios), o qual \xc3\xa9 realizado, nesta data, por meio de of\xc3\xadcio enviado \xc3\xa0 Receita Federal, protocolado eletronicamente, por interm\xc3\xa9dio do sistema INFOJUD. Intime-se. - ADV: MATHEUS DE OLIVEIRA TAVARES (OAB 160711/SP)', ''), ('Processo 1056922-84.2013.8.26.0100 - Execu\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o de T\xc3\xadtulo Extrajudicial - Esp\xc3\xa9cies de Contratos - MOBILINS FORMA\xc3\x87\xc3\x83O PROFISSIONAL EM BELEZA LTDA. - JULIANA MARANH\xc3\x83O PORTO DA SILVEIRA - Vistos. 1) Ci\xc3\xaancia da resposta do of\xc3\xadcio expedido \xc3\xa0 Receita Federal, ficando os dados sigilosos arquivados em pasta pr\xc3\xb3pria. 2) Por conseguinte, a parte exequente deve manifestar-se, em cinco dias. No sil\xc3\xaancio, ao arquivo. Intime-se. - ADV: MATHEUS DE OLIVEIRA TAVARES (OAB 160711/SP)', ''), ('', 'Processo 1057280-15.2014.8.26.0100')]
```

If both inputs are legal (i.e. the input may contain the word *Process* and may contain the word *Processo*), then this regular expression should be used:

```
>>> regex = re.compile('(Processo? \\d{7}\\-\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}\\.\\d+\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}.*?)(?=Processo?)|(Processo? \\d{7}\\-\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}\\.\\d+\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}.*)')
```